# Wrong redirection for [href]

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a tag with bind [href].
When I go to link my page goes me to link with 'localhost/LINK-VALUE'

```
<td><a target="_blank" [href]="client.data.websiteUrl"> {{ client.data.websiteUrl }}</a></td>
```

Why is this happening?

If my website url is for example `wwww.google.com`, my page takes me to `localhost/www.gooogle.com`

Comment: Did you try to console log `client.data.websiteUrl` value?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. I am reverting this to its previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "http://" in front of your LINK_VALUE. So, it would be -

```
<td><a target="_blank" [href]="'href://' + client.data.websiteUrl"> {{ client.data.websiteUrl }} </a></td>
```